# How to get data attributes from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div
    data-global-messages="{&quot;addCartSuccessMessage&quot;:&quot;successfully added&quot;,&quot;creditRepresentativeMessage&quot;:&quot;Please contact your Credit Representative&quot;,&quot;nonStockMessage&quot;:&quot;Non-stock item&quot;,&quot;addWishlistSuccessMessage&quot;:&quot;Wish List.&quot;,&quot;itemExistsCartMessage&quot;:&quot;Please review error(s) below.&nbsp;&quot;,&quot;itemExistsWishlistMessage&quot;:&quot;Please review error(s) below.&nbsp;&quot;,&quot;nonAvailableMessage&quot;:&quot;substitute.&quot;,&quot;creditDepartmentMessage&quot;:&quot;Please contact Sea.&nbsp;&quot;}">
  </div>
```

How to get the attributes from above?

I tried `document.querySelector('data-global-messages').getAttribute('addCartSuccessMessage')` which returns null

Answer (score 1):

All data attributes are stored in the element's `dataset` property.
To access it you can do:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('div[data-global-messages]');
const data = element.dataset.globalMessages;
const json = JSON.parse(data);
```